# Problema al insertar datos PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Dicha funcion que tiene que hacer es insertar, el Menu, el SubMenu y Platos y insertarlo con sus ids correspondientes en una tabla llamada mapeo que contiene id_menu | id_sub_menu | id_plato.
El problema es que al insertarlo me inserta los platos en todos los submenus.

```
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'altaMenu')) {
    $menu->setNombre($_POST['nombreMenu']);
    $menu->setPrecio($_POST['precioMenu']);
    $id_menu = $crudMenu->insertar($menu);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['nombreSubMenu']); $i++) {
        print_r($_POST['nombreSubMenu'][$i]);
        $id_submenu = $crudMenu->insertarSubMenu($_POST['nombreSubMenu'][$i]);

        /*platos*/
        $array = $_POST['platos'];
        foreach ($array as $key) {
            //echo $key;
            $plato->setIdMenu('');
            $plato->setNombre($key);
            $plato->setPrecio('');
            $plato->setTipo('1');
            var_dump($plato);
            $id_plato = $crudPlato->insertar($plato);
            echo $id_plato;

            $crudMenu->insertMapSubMenu($id_menu,$id_submenu,$id_plato);   
        }
    }
    print '<br><b>Menu -> '.$id_menu.'. SubMenu -> '.$id_submenu.'. Plato -> '.$id_plato.'</b>';
    /**/
}
```

El problema que me estoy encontrando es que al insertar los datos tabla por tabla no me da ningún problema y puedo mostrar los datos sin problema, pero si hago uso de las lineas de código de arriba solo me muestra los platos de un submenu.

```
 public function insertarSubMenu($nombre){
        $cnx = conexion::conectar();

        try{
            $sentencia = $cnx->prepare('INSERT INTO submenu VALUES(:id,:nombre)');
            $sentencia->execute(array(':id' => '',':nombre' => $nombre));
            return $cnx->lastInsertId();
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'Error -> '.$e->getMessage();
        }

    }



public function insertMapSubMenu($id_menu,$id_submenu,$id_plato){
        $cnx = conexion::conectar();

        $sentencia = $cnx->prepare('INSERT INTO map_submenu VALUES(:id,:id_submenu,:id_menu,:id_plato)');
        $sentencia->execute([':id' => '', ':id_submenu' => $id_submenu, ':id_menu' => $id_menu, ':id_plato' => $id_plato]);
    }

public function insertar($menu){
    $cnx = conexion::conectar();
    try{
        $sentencia = $cnx->prepare('INSERT INTO menu VALUES (:id,:nombre,:precio)');
        $sentencia->execute(array('id' => $menu->getIdMenu(),'nombre' => $menu->getNombre(),'precio' => $menu->getPrecio()));
        return $cnx->lastInsertId();
    } catch(PDOExceptio $e){
        echo 'Error con mensaje -> '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que hace eso porque así se lo indicas aquí: `$id_submenu = $crudMenu->insertarSubMenu($_POST['nombreSubMenu'][$i]);`  ¿o bien aquí: `$id_plato = $crudPlato->insertar($plato);`?

Comment: Mmm en esas funciones tengo un metodo que me devuelve el ultimo id insertado para recuperar el id del ultimo submenu para que así sea su corresponiendente, creo que es ahi donde ocurre el error...

Comment: Pues revisa esas funciones, puede que en alguna de ellas se haga un `INSERT` o se invoque a otra función que lo haga. Si no encuentras nada de eso en ellas, revisa a la misma función `insertMapSubMenu`, donde también podría estar ocurriendo que se haga dicha inserción que no deseas.

Comment: Bff me gustaría poder explicarte el problema con mas detenimiento, como podemos hacer una sala privada?

Comment: Fíjate que no sé como se abren las salas de chat y la verdad que los chats me gustan muy poco. No obstante voy a ver cómo se abre un debate en chat.

Comment: Si inserto los datos de forma manual tabla por tabla y las enlazo no tengo problema, y cuando los inserto así es cuando tengo problema pero al revisar la base de datos todo parece estar correcto

Comment: No encuentro la opción para crear un chat. Pero podrías explicar un poco el problema editando la pregunta, así podrás obtener el punto de vista y los comentarios de varios compañeros, si fuera el caso. Siempre es más enriquecedor que plantearlo en privado. Puedes poner el código de `insertarSubMenu`, de `insertar` y de `insertMapSubMenu` para revisarlo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77815/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-sergibarca).